# CASE in WHERE Mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with languages in.

The table

lan_dish_id | lan_dish_lang | lan_dish_dishid | lan_dish_mainlang
--------------- | ------------------- | --------------------- | ------------------------
1                 | nl                     | 8                        | 1
4                 | fr                      | 8                        | 0

I need to check if the language in the `$_SESSION['lang']` is available in the table, otherwise it must take the mainlanguage.

Unfortunatly, when running following query, he returns the row with FR and also with NL als lan_dish_lan... In this case it has only to return the row with FR.

```
SELECT * FROM `language_dish` WHERE 
(CASE
 WHEN lan_dish_lang = "fr"
 THEN lan_dish_lang = "fr"
 ELSE lan_dish_mainlang = 1
 END) AND lan_dish_dishid = 8
```

Comment: You asked [the same question, with a different title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46511749/using-case-in-where-clause), 3 hours ago

Comment: Sql does not stop reading rows when a case statement is satisfied in a where clause and since your where clause evaluates to true for both rows then both rows are returned.

Answer (score 1):

Here's 2 ways which might work for you.

```
/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;

CREATE TABLE T (lan_dish_id INT, lan_dish_lang VARCHAR(2), lan_dish_dishid INT, lan_dish_mainlang INT);
*/
truncate table t;
INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1                 , 'nl' , 8,                         1) ,
(4                 , 'fr' , 8,                         0) ,
(5                 , 'nl' , 9,                         1) ,
(6                 , 'de' , 7,                         0) 

;

select s.lan_dish_dishid, left(gc,instr(concat(gc,','),',') -1) lang
from
(
select lan_dish_dishid, group_concat(lan_dish_lang order by lan_dish_mainlang) gc
from t
#where lan_dish_dishid = 8
group by lan_dish_dishid
order by lan_dish_dishid
) s
;
select s.lan_dish_id, s.lan_dish_lang
from
(
select t.*,
         if(t.lan_dish_dishid <> @p , @rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,
         @p:= t.lan_dish_dishid p
from t , (select @rn:=0,@p:=0) r
order by t.lan_dish_dishid, t.lan_dish_Mainlang
) s where s.rn = 1
```

Result

```
+-------------+---------------+
| lan_dish_id | lan_dish_lang |
+-------------+---------------+
|           6 | de            |
|           4 | fr            |
|           5 | nl            |
+-------------+---------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: I see, but this is not the required result. If the row with FR in column lan_dish_lang exists, it need to show that row. Otherwise, if it doesn't exist, it need to show the row where lan_dish_mainlang = 1 for that particular lan_dish_dishid. I hope you understand it...

Comment: I'm all agog - what is the expected result given the sample data I posted?

Comment: I'm getting the row with FR. Ok, but if the row with FR doesn't exist it need to show the row where the column lan_dish_mainlang = 1

Comment: In my sample data lan_dish_id 5 fails to find FR and returns nl , is that not correct?

Comment: I see, but what for 6? It’s not FR and not the mainlang

Comment: But it is the only lang for 6.

Comment: If it’s the only language, lan_dish_mainlang is Always 1

Comment: I’m winderig why the CASE is not working. Al I doing something wrong?